# Why does high resolution clock from chrono library output 0 and reasonable values in seemingly random order?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a function that I was using the chrono library to benchmark- at times the output would be zero for time passed and sometimes a more reasonable value- in my case about 973,300 nanoseconds. I would like to know why this behaviour occurs specifically- as in why sometimes the output is zero but sometimes the 973,300 nanoseconds I mentioned above. I understand that there is a limit on precision intrinsic to any machine, but the fact that there is an output at times 0 or at other times more reasonable is what is getting to me.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void megu()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++);
}

int main()
{
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    megu();
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start);
    cout << duration.count();

    return 0;
}
```

I attempted to run the code with longer and shorter run time functions (larger maximum value for `i` in function `megu` here, and it only happens with shorter run times. This points to it being a precision issue- if it was not for the "reasonable" values outputted in between the zero's having a low variance- maximum of 20 nanoseconds of difference between them (within that 973,300 nanosecond window). The sudden zero's then, have to be due to something else. I also tried running the function as many times as necessary in order to get X amount of reasonable values to take a decent average, and I do get enough of these reasonable values every time within a single program execution using a loop that discards 0 values (no batch file etc).

I am on Windows 11, Intel i7 processor.

Comment: The call to `megu` may be optimized away. Also, don't use `high_resolution_clock`. Use `steady_clock`

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++);` violates the [progress guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) because it has no side effects.

Comment: @heapunderrun It isn't an infinite loop, so it doesn't violate forward-progress. But the compiler will optimize it away most likely.

Comment: @OP The compiler outsmarted you and saw that the loop has no side-effects.  Thus there is no need to call it.  As a better example, how about filling a vector with a million random values, start the timer, call `std::sort` on those values, stop the timer, and output the first and last values in the vector, as well as the time it took `std::sort` to sort the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is smart enough to recognize that the loop in `megu` does nothing. Therefore this function call is completely optimized away.

You can check this by looking on the assembly via [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/G1bWfrdTh).

```
megu():
  ret
main:
  pushq %rbx
  call std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
  movq %rax, %rbx
  call std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
  movl $_ZSt4cout, %edi
  subq %rbx, %rax
  movq %rax, %rsi
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<long>(long)
  xorl %eax, %eax
  popq %rbx
  ret
```